# Draw a shape on a map by driving distance, not as the crow flies

Tags: r, mapping

In R, if i draw a shape on a map using leaflet, it will create a circle with a radius I specify.

```
data <- data.frame(location = "George Bush International Airport",
                   lat = 29.990665933195277,
                   long = -95.33663249561174,
                   radius =48280.3 )

#map it
leaflet(data, height = 1000, width = 1000) %>%
  addTiles() %>% addCircles(data = data, lng = ~data$long, lat = ~data$lat, weight = 1,
    radius = ~data$radius) %>% 
  leaflet.extras::addSearchOSM(options = searchOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

[image]

Instead of the shape being a simple circle with a radius I specify, is it possible to draw a shape that represents 30 miles driving in any direction? Like this image below (screen shot taken from smappen.com but i have to pay to use it and export everything)
[image]

Id be open to doing this anywhere for free, not just R.

Comment: Those polygons are usually referred to as isodistances. Are you looking for a free service that would generate those for you or a way to generate those yourself? For the latter, do you already have road network data? Are we talking about just few polygons for pre-defined locations or will there be hundreds or thousands of such requests per day? What about the delay, is 1s / 10s / 30s wait time acceptable?

Comment: Very similar to this question, and its answers might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047722/find-locations-with-the-same-travel-time-to-a-destination-heatmap-contours-base/51094785#51094785

Comment: @margusl I am open to any application that will do it. I like R, and i map in it with leaflet frequently, but i dont really care. It just needs to be shareable. I only have 3-5 areas i need to create once, and im not worried about the delay at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those shapes are usually referred to as isodistances. [osrm](https://github.com/riatelab/osrm) package provides easy to use interface for [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) routing service and comes with `osrmIsodistance()` function that returns `sf` object (a dataframe with support for geometries) with a multipolygon. `sf` is well-supported by Leaflet , so we can just add it as a polygon layer. For convenience, we'll also store source locations in `sf` object.

By default `osrm` uses an OSRM demo server which is not really suitable for heavy traffic and high request rate ( [usage policy](https://routing.openstreetmap.de/about.html) ), though it should be fine for generating a limited set of isodistance polygons.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(osrm)
library(leaflet)
library(tictoc)

# store locations in sf object
points_sf <- tibble(location = "George Bush International Airport",
                    lat = 29.990665933195277, 
                    long = -95.33663249561174,
                    radius = 48280.3 ) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = "WGS84")
points_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -95.33663 ymin: 29.99067 xmax: -95.33663 ymax: 29.99067
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   location                          radius             geometry
#> * <chr>                              <dbl>          <POINT [°]>
#> 1 George Bush International Airport 48280. (-95.33663 29.99067)

## 30-mile / 48km isodistance polyon
# loc: takes only a single location or first location from dataframe / sf
# breaks: vector of isodistance areas, i.e. c(10000, 25000, 50000) to generate 3 polygons
# res: number of points for one side of square grid, default is (much faster) 30
# tic-toc for timing
tic("osrmIsodistance")
isodist_sf <- osrmIsodistance(loc    = points_sf[1,],
                              breaks = points_sf$radius[1],
                              res    = 100)
toc()
#> osrmIsodistance: 162.23 sec elapsed

resulting sf object:
isodist_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -95.73746 ymin: 29.62006 xmax: -94.87008 ymax: 30.32588
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   id isomin  isomax                       geometry
#> 1  1      0 48280.3 MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.1592 30...

# leaflet supports sf object, no need to specify lng/lat for markers, polygons
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data = isodist_sf, weight = 1, group = "Isodistance") %>% 
  addMarkers(data = points_sf, label = ~ location, group = "Locations") %>% 
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("Isodistance", "Locations"), 
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful. A work of art. I'm not sure i could have asked for anything better.

Answer (score 1):

`googleway::google_directions` or `google_distance` should do it (with a bit of wrangling). See the vignette: http://symbolixau.github.io/googleway/articles/googleway-vignette.html